# Display SQL data in PHP

Tags: php, html, sql

Hi users of Stack Overflow,

I am facing a issue where my SQL data won't display properly and I am not sure on how to fix this problem. I only see the print section with no appropriate data.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/default.css" type="text/css" />
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/timetable.css" type="text/css" />
<title>Timetable Information</title>
</head>
<body>


<div id="header"></div>


<ul id="NavigationList">
<li><a href="Index.php">Index</a></li>
<li><a href="ModuleInfo.php">Module Info</a></li>
<li><a href="ModuleSearch.php">Module Search</a></li>
<li><a href="Timetable.php">Timetable Search</a></li>

</ul>
<p>
<p>Please select a school from the drop-down list.</p>

   <?php
require('json.php');
error_reporting(E_ALL);
$connection = mysql_connect('localhost', 'root','') or
    die("Could not connect: " . mysql_error());
mysql_select_db("timetable") or die("No such database");
$sql = sprintf("
  SELECT id,day,start,module
    FROM event JOIN teaches ON (event.id=teaches.event)
   WHERE staff='%s'", mysql_real_escape_string($_REQUEST['staff']));
$result = mysql_query($sql)
  or die(mysql_error());
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
    print "<div>$row[id] $row[module] $row[day] $row[start]</div>\n";
}
?>
</p>
<div id="Footer">
            <p id="FooterText">Copyright &copy; 2012 .<br     />All     rights reserved.</p>    
            </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: `mysql_connect('localhost', 'root','')` - nice nice )

Comment: should there be quotes around the field names?

Comment: Please remove error reporting and post the error you will get. So that we can able to debug it more accurately.

Comment: @RohitKumarChoudhary I am recieving no error, All I get displayed is {$row['id']} {$row['module']} {$row['day']} {$row['start']}\n"; } ?>

Comment: Try to print just the SQL query and run it to see if it even shows any data there

Comment: @Sachyn Nothing is shown, Perhaps it's not reading from the file correctly?

Comment: How come nothing is shown? You can just use `echo $sql; exit();` before this line `$result = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());`. The SQL query will get printed in browser that you can test

Comment: use print_r($row); if it contains value then echo your value do not use print

Comment: @Sachyn I have added that line in but it still shows nothing. It's just blank. 

<?php
require('json.php');
$connection = mysql_connect("sqlzoo.net", "timetable", "timetable") or
    die("Could not connect: " . mysql_error());
mysql_select_db("timetable") or die("No such database");
$sql = sprintf("
  SELECT id,day,start,module
    FROM event JOIN teaches ON (event.id=teaches.event)
   WHERE staff='%s'", mysql_real_escape_string($_REQUEST['staff']));
echo $sql; exit();
$result = mysql_query($sql)
  or die(mysql_error());
?>

Comment: Strange. Just 1 question. What is `%s` in your query? Did you try removing the single quotes? If not then please try `WHERE staff=%s"`

Comment: @Sachyn Hm, its a string place holder. I am still confused on how I can get this data to be displayed from the SQL file. I have tried removing the quotes and it makes no difference.

Comment: Try this way - `$sStaff = mysql_real_escape_string($_REQUEST['staff']);  
$sql = "SELECT id,day,start,module FROM event JOIN teaches ON (event.id=teaches.event) WHERE staff = ".$sStaff;`

Comment: @Sachyn Still displays the print part, no sql is displayed by using echo $sql; exit();

Comment: Maybe `mysql_real_escape_string()` is creating problem. Try temporarily removing that.

Comment: @Sachyn I removed that line also but it still displays the print part of the code.

Answer (score 1):

Use:

```
print "<div>{$row['id']} {$row['module']} {$row['day']} {$row['start']}</div>\n";
```

Instead of:

```
print "<div>$row[id] $row[module] $row[day] $row[start]</div>\n";
```

Comment: I have changed it, but it only displays the line and not the data within the table.

Comment: Are you sure that `mysql_num_rows($result)` returns a value more than 0?

Answer (score 1):

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) { 
    $symbol= $row['Symbol'];
    $date= $row['Date']; 
    $avgprice= $row['avg_price']; 
    $var4 = $row['field4']
    ."<br>";


    echo "<tr>
        <td >".$symbol."</td>
        <td >".$date."</td>
        <td >".$avgprice."</td>
        <td >".$var4."</td>

    </tr>";
```

Answer (score 0):

Try This

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
echo "<div>".$row['id'];
echo $row['module'];
echo $row['day'];
echo $row['start'];
echo "</div>";
}
```

Instead of:
   print "$row[id] $row[module] $row[day] $row[start]\n";

Comment: Displays this - ".$row['id']; echo $row['module']; echo $row['day']; echo $row['start']; echo ""; } ?>

Comment: try this$sql = "SELECT id,day,start,module
    FROM event JOIN teaches ON (event.id=teaches.event)
   WHERE staff='%s'", mysql_real_escape_string($_REQUEST['staff']);
$result = mysql_query($sql)

Answer (score 0):

try something like this

```
print "<div>".$row[id]. $row[module]. $row[day]. $row[start]."</div>\n";
```